# pod install causes error: The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies

Tags: ios, flutter, tensorflow-lite

> pod install
> Analyzing dependencies
> Downloading dependencies
> Installing DKImagePickerController (4.3.4)
> Installing DKPhotoGallery (0.0.17)
> Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
> Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
> Installing SDWebImage (5.18.8)
> Installing SwiftyGif (5.4.4)
> Installing TensorFlowLiteC (2.14.0)
> Installing TensorFlowLiteSwift (2.14.0)
> Installing ffmpeg-kit-ios-https (6.0)
> Installing ffmpeg_kit_flutter (6.0.3)
> Installing file_picker (0.0.1)
> Installing image_picker_ios (0.0.1)
> Installing path_provider_foundation (0.0.1)
> Installing photo_manager (1.0.0)
> Installing shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1)
> Installing sqflite (0.0.3)
> Installing tflite_flutter (0.1.0)
> Installing video_player_avfoundation (0.0.1)
> [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (TensorFlowLiteSwift)

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Debug `UUID=`331C8088294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `AE0B7B92F70575B8D7E0D07E` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Release `UUID=`331C8089294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `89B67EB44CE7B6631473024E` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Profile `UUID=`331C808A294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `640959BDD8F10B91D80A66BE` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`RunnerTests `UUID=`331C8080294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `331C807E294A63A400263BE5` for attribute: `build_phases`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

tried rm -rf ios/Pod, flutter clean; flutter build;
None of these works.

Answer (score 0):

Detinageate the pod file and then after install it and then update the pod from this you can solve your problem.